WaterMark Bot Not Deploying
My Error
I just deploying a simple watermark telegram bot and getting stuck with these error. Please help me with this if you can. Same error persists render, and on local PC, neither, one of them works for me.
Can't I know what to write here?
>     ==> Running 'python3 bot.py'
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/opt/render/project/src/bot.py", line 552, in <module>
>         AHBot.run()
>       File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/run.py",
> line 58, in run
>         self.start()
>       File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/sync.py",
> line 66, in async_to_sync_wrap
>         return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
>                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 654, in run_until_complete
>         return future.result()
>                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>       File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/start.py",
> line 52, in start
>         is_authorized = await self.connect()
>                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>       File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/auth/connect.py",
> line 38, in connect
>         self.load_config()
>       File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/client.py",
> line 616, in load_config
>         raise AttributeError("No API Key found. More info: https://docs.pyrogram.org/intro/setup")
>     AttributeError: No API Key found. More info: https://docs.pyrogram.org/intro/setup


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Also, please read [mre]. Come back and [edit] your question once you've read both articles so we can better help you solve your problem!

From what I can see, you are trying to get the environment variable "LOG_CHANNEL", which doesn't exist, and try to cast that into an integer. Nothing cannot be turned into an integer.

@SteinGaming Thnx buddy but now i getting these errors
